# Non-metrizable smooth manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Is it possible to find a smooth manifold on which it is impossible to define a metric function?

Comment: It depends. How do you define “smooth manifold”?

Comment: A smooth manifold can be given a metric using a partition of unity.

Comment: Do you want to talk about metric tensor or distance function?

Comment: For example [the long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology))?

Comment: I am talking about the usual definition, a manifold with a smooth structure(A maximal atlas),  sorry I am inexperienced in topology.

Comment: I am talking about distance function.

Comment: By the Whitney embedding theorem, any smooth manifold can be thought of as being inside some Euclidean space $R^N$ (you can take $N$ to be twice the dimension of the manifold). You can now define your distance function on the manifold as the restriction of the usual distance function in Euclidean space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the definition of a smooth manifold $M$. Usually one requires that $M$

1) is Hausdorff,

2) is second countable,

3) has a smooth atlas.

The "minimal" requirement for a smooth manifold would be 3), but obviously 1) is a necessary condition for the existence of a metric. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold for examples of non-Hausdorff manifolds.

That 2) is necessary for the for the existence of a metric is less obvious. As a counterexample take the *long line* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology).

If 1) - 3) are satisfied, then deb's and Aleksandar Milivojevic's comments show that $M$ is metrizable.